# Using spin lock to lock a variable being concurrently used in a different thread?

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, concurrency, spinlock

Say you call spin_lock(&key) and key is having some type of operation being performed on it in a different thread at the same time. Is the other thread being paused/interrupted?

What happens to the other thread that's in the middle of altering or using key? Such as if the thread was calling copy_to_user(key), copy_from_user(key) or kmallocing/kfreeing key?

Comment: You should only perform operations on shared data inside an exclusive lock.

Comment: You're talking about the `spin_lock` inside the kernel?  I thought the argument to `spin_lock` was a pointer to the lock itself.  There isn't really any kind of operation you can do on a lock except to lock or unlock it, and of course it is safe to attempt those concurrently.

Comment: If you're asking about operations on the data object(s) that the spinlock is meant to be protecting, then no, taking the lock does not in any way pause, interrupt, or roll back those operations.   Therefore the other thread ought to have locked the spinlock before performing those operations in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't know specifically about [Linux kernel `spin_lock()`](https://0xax.gitbooks.io/linux-insides/content/SyncPrim/linux-sync-1.html), but in practically all programming environments, [mutex locking is *advisory*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lock_(computer_science)). That means, locking a lock never prevents *anything* except, it prevents other threads from locking the same lock at the same time. If you want to use a lock to protect some variable or data structure, then it's entirely the programmer's responsibility to ensure that no code anywhere in the system ever accesses the data except when the lock is locked.